# Should I use window.onload event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Perhaps this is a duplicate question, but I wanted to ask.

I want to make a JS application that does not use third party libraries, for the purpose of learning JS events within a browser.

So I structured my app like this:

```
var APP = APP || (function (global) {
   return {
       digitsField: {},
       // other properties, methods
       init: function (config) {
          try {
              this.digitsField = global.getElementById('digitsField');
              return this;
          } catch (error) {
              console.log(error.message);
              return false;
          };
       }
   };
} (window.document));
```

My html page looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="APP.init({});">
         <input type="text" value="0" class="textField" readonly="true" id="digitsField"/>
         // other html tags
    </body>
</html>
```

Though I send `window.document` to my immediate function, `digitsField` tag is still not defined for other workings until the page is loaded or until I call `APP.init()` function. I also noticed in Firebug, in the DOM tab that there is is global row dedicated to `onload` event which kind of clutters the global namespace. Perhaps there is better way to initialize `APP.digitsField` to the tag object without using `window.onload` event or third party libraries?

Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window onload event fires when everything is loaded, including external resources. You should however only need to wait for the DOM load, so you can attach a handler to the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // code...
});
```

This should be working in browsers newer than IE8 (So IE9 and above).

Comment: yeah it works. Ok, before accept the answer as correct how would you incorporate this event into my JS code? I just added three lines window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event){
 APP.init({"event": event});
}); after defining APP. Is it ok like this?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be in order.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the same benefit of DOM ready, with full-browser compatibility, just move your code to inside the closing tag of the body element.

e.g.

```
<body>
     <input type="text" value="0" class="textField" readonly="true" id="digitsField"/>
     // other html tags
     <script>
         APP.init({});
     </script>
</body>
```

Otherwise consider moving to jQuery and its DOM ready event, which a handles browser compatibility issues for you.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   APP.init({});
});
```

or the shortcut version:

```
$(function(){
   APP.init({});
});
```

The jQuery version can be placed anywhere (header, body etc)